# How to search(filter) in nested map and return entire map elements

Tags: android, flutter, dart, nested-map

I am trying to filter the map and in return, I want every filtered map element.

**Code:-**

```
Map<String, Map<int, int>> temp = {Basic Terms: {1: 0}, Table and Column Naming Rules: {1: 1}};
var temp = temp.keys.where(element) => element.contains("basic"));
print(temp);
```

**Output:-**

```
I/flutter (30857): (Basic Terms)
```

**Output I want** :-

```
I/flutter (30857): {Basic Terms: {1: 0}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to iterate over `entries` not `keys`, and then convert the `List<MapEntry>` back to a `Map`:

```dart
Map<String, Map<int, int>> temp = {
  'Basic Terms': {1: 0}, 
  'Table and Column Naming Rules': {1: 1}
};

var temp2 = Map.fromEntries(
  temp.entries.where(
    (entry) => entry.key.contains('Basic Terms')
  )
);
print(temp2);
```

Which outputs:

```
{Basic Terms: {1: 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Map<int, int>> temp = {'Basic Terms': {1: 0}, 'Table and Column Naming Rules': {1: 1}};
  var thisTemp = temp.entries.firstWhere((element) => element.key.contains("Basic"));
  print(thisTemp.toString());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.